# adding dynamically border to the nested div element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have set of divisions.
I have to add the border to  the nested div(trending-description) on clicking of the above div(trending) using jquery.

```
 <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 trending">

           <div class="trending-description">Loan Count</div>
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 trending">

           <div class="trending-description">% of sample</div>
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 trending">

           <div class="trending-description">% of sample</div>
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 trending">

           <div class="trending-description">% of sample</div>
       </div>

    </div>
```

I have created [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zb14n86r/) Please tell me where have done the mistake.,

Comment: Do you want to apply this border on click or hover? Your fiddle uses hover.

Comment: @SureshRamesh [Is this](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/zb14n86r/1/) what you wanted

Comment: Your code works fine in my opinion :-) Did you mean  different type of border: 2px solid #23b7e5; ?  (not just bottom border)

Comment: @SureshRamesh glad I could help. If it worked for you, please accept my answer below.

Comment: @LShetty Sorry to say this I don't have enough credits to up-vote your answer. I  am new to the stack-overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$(".trending").click(function () {
    $('.trending-description').removeClass('trending-description-active ')
    $(this).find('.trending-description').addClass('trending-description-active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/zb14n86r/2/

```
$(".trending").click(function () {
    $('.trending-description').removeClass('trending-description-active');
    $(this).find('.trending-description').addClass('trending-description-active');
});
```